# Inicidencias al subir algunas imagenes al Server con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, imagen, servidor

### SOLUCIONADO EL PROBLEMA.

---

El problema ya esta solucionado y os lo explico a continuación por si a alguien mas le ocurre lo mismo.

El código inicialmente funcionaba sin ningún problema pero a la hora de subir las imágenes algunas de ellas fallaban y se subían de forma corrupta o ni se subían al servidor.

Tras probar mil formas de subir los archivos encontré el fallo y no estaba en el código sino en la configuración de xampp/wampp. Estos programas por defecto tienen configurado un limite de memoria para utilizar en los formularios que suele ser bastante bajo en mi caso era de 2M lo que hice es aumentarlo a 12GB y problema solucionado!!

Los pasos que seguí son los siguientes: (con xampp)

1. Acceder al directorio de xampp
2. Entrar en php y buscar php.ini
3. Editar con el notepad u otro editor y buscar las siguientes lineas de código:

   ```
   memory_limit (al ser un server dedicado le puse el 80% de la RAM disponible.)
   upload_max (estaba en 2M y lo puse en 12000M unos 11GB)
   post_max_size(estaba en 2M y lo puse en 12000M unos 11GB)
   ```

El primer parámetro es el limite total de php para trabajar en memoria por lo que siempre tiene que ser igual o superior a los otros dos, el segundo es la memoria máxima que utiliza a la hora de subir archivos (que es donde residía mi problema) y el tercer campo es para enviar con el método POST el formulario completo.

Espero que os sirva de ayuda por que es un problema muy común y no he encontrado nada relacionado en foros de como solucionarlo , suerte a los demás!

---

---

### ## ERROR AL SUBIR IMÁGENES TENIENDO BIEN EL CÓDIGO, TANTO A LA BBDD COMO AL SERVER ##

Llevo unas semanas enfrentándome a un error curioso que no logro ver solucionado en ningún foro de Internet.

Tengo una web donde se suben imagenes a traves de un codigo bastante sencillo y un formulario sencillo , las imagenes la mayoria se suben sin problema alguno y sin ninguna incidencia. Pero hay ciertas imagenes (no logro ver que tieen en comun) que fallan a la hora de subirse al sevidor.

He probado todo lo que se me ha ocurrido he intentado almacenarlas tanto en la BBDD como moverlas a una carpeta en el server pero el error persiste con esas imagenes y no logro saber por que es... os dejo el codigo del .php

```
<?php
SESSION_START();
error_reporting(-1);
$nom = $_SESSION['nombreusuario'];
$conexion= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","elarbusto");


$caracteres='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
$longpalabra=8;
for($pass123='', $n=strlen($caracteres)-1; strlen($pass123) < $longpalabra ; ) {
  $x = rand(0,$n);
  $pass123.= $caracteres[$x];
}

$ruta="./ImagenesWEB/AvatarPerfil/";//ruta carpeta donde queremos copiar las imágenes 
$uploadfile_temporal=$_FILES['Logo']['tmp_name']; 
$uploadfile_nombre=$ruta.$_FILES['Logo']['name']; 

$extension = ".".end(explode(".", $_FILES['Logo']['name']));
$nombre = $nom.date('Y-m-d').$pass123.$extension;
$nombreComp = $ruta.$nombre;


if (is_uploaded_file($uploadfile_temporal)) 
{ 
    move_uploaded_file($uploadfile_temporal,$nombreComp); 
    $modusuarioLider = "UPDATE `usuarios` SET `Avatar` = '.$nombreComp' WHERE `Nick` = '$nom' ";
    $realizarmod = mysqli_query($conexion, $modusuarioLider);   
    header("location:cuerpoweb/INDPerfil.php");


} 
else 
{ 
header("location:cuerpoweb/INDPerfil.php?error=4");
} 





mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Si algun enviado del cielo es capaz de ayudarme se agradeceria bastante!

## AÑADO CONTENIDO PARA ACLARAR MAS EL TEMA:

A petición del amigo Oscar subo una version mas sencilla del código, tanto de un html como del php:

subirimagencarpeta.html:
    
    
    Documento sin título

```
<body>
<form action="subirimagencarpeta2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    Archivo: <input name="fichero" type="file"> 
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload!">  
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

subirimagencarpeta2.php:

```
<?php 
$ruta="./pruebaimagenes/";//ruta carpeta donde queremos copiar las imágenes 
$uploadfile_temporal=$_FILES['fichero']['tmp_name']; 
$uploadfile_nombre=$ruta.$_FILES['fichero']['name']; 

$extension = ".".end(explode(".", $_FILES['fichero']['name']));


if (is_uploaded_file($uploadfile_temporal)) 
{ 
    move_uploaded_file($uploadfile_temporal,$ruta.'ejemplonombre'.$extension); 
} 
else 
{ 
echo "error"; 
} 



?> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Documento sin t&iacute;tulo</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
</head> 

<body> 

    <?php  echo "<img src=".$ruta.'ejemplonombre'.$extension.">";  ?>

</body> 
</html>
```

Creo que si me dejara adjuntar imágenes, aquí tienes una que no permite subir y otra que si. (no me deja subir las imagenes por tamaño, os las dejo en un enlace)

Imagen que no deja subir: https://ibb.co/eHMebK

Imagen que si permite subir: https://ibb.co/mi00iz

Comment: ¿Que mensaje lanza cuando te da error? Puedes editar tu pregunta y añadirlo ahí para ampliar la información para otros usuarios que entren.

Comment: La cosa es que no muestra ningun mensaje de error... en el if / else se salta el if y se va al else lo que me hace sospechar que no se esta descargando bien la imagen para luego subirla a la carpeta del servidor pero no sale nada mas

Comment: Interesante y extraño al mismo tiempo. Personalmente, aislaría el código básico para realizar distintas pruebas e intentar detectar que produce el `false` en `is_uploaded_file `. Prueba a editar las imágenes que no suben, a ver si al crear un derivado si lo hace.

Comment: Ya he realizado esas modificaciones por eso he venido aqui a pedir ayuda jeje la cosa es muy curiosa, si abro la imagen con un editor y la guardo de nuevo con otro nombre sin tocar nada pero la misma extension no da errores, lo que no logro entender es el patron de las imagenes que produce el error.

Comment: Lo desconozco la verdad, pero me ha pasado, no esto que comentas, pero si otro tipo de errores, y los solucionaba editando la imagen antes de pasarla a su directorio de destino (de ahí el comentario anterior). Después al terminar elimina la imagen temporal que es la que producía errores.

Comment: Propones entonces que edite la imagen con php en el propio codigo antes de subirla? he subido una version del codigo mas sencilla como pedias y dos imagenes de muestra

Comment: Ya esta eliminado el comentario cuando sepas algo mas si es que logras ver lo que yo no veo me avisas , gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: He añadido la respuesta tras haber realizado algunas pruebas. por cierto, Bienvenido!! Buen comienzo!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente mi conclusión es que la imagen está corrupta por algún motivo.

Cualquier imagen al pasarla a la función  `getimagesize` para obtener sus 
dimensiones y otra información retorna un *array*.

Ejemplo de la imagen que si sube:

```
array (size=3)
  'filesize' => int 154007
  'filename' => string '74.png' (length=6)
  'size' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => int 512
      1 => int 512
      2 => int 3
      3 => string 'width="512" height="512"' (length=24)
      'bits' => int 8
      'mime' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
```

En cambio, la imagen que no sube retorna la siguiente información:

```
array (size=3)
  'filesize' => int 0
  'filename' => string 'imagen.png' (length=10)
  'size' => boolean false
```

Además del correspondiente Warning:

> Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in /var/www/phptest/httpdocs

Esto nos trae otro problema añadido, al no poder obtener las dimensiones
no podemos editarla puesto que no sabemos que proporciones darle.

Así que antes de llegar al condicional `is_uploaded_file` es mejor pasar
la imagen por `getimagesize` y comprobar que contiene los datos mínimos
para poder tratarla.
(*Opinión personal*) De lo contrario, descartarla e informar al usuario
que la imagen no se puede subir. Incluso añadir indicaciones de posibles soluciones, como por ejemplo lo que hemos hablado que sabemos que si funciona, que es pasarla antes por un editor de imágenes y volver a guardarla.

Comment: Interesante lo que mencionas no he probado lo de obtener el tamaño por que no era importante para lo que quiero de la imagen pero puede ser, lo que me preocupa es que ocurre con TODAS las fotos que se toman desde el telefono al "hacer una foto" no se como funcionara internamente lo del telefono para que falle asi.

Comment: Voy a hacer un par de pruebas mas a ver que si logro sacar algo mas en claro pero por ahora hare lo que mencionas y avisare al usuario de posibles soluciones, gracias por todo Oscar!

Comment: @Guillermo Si que es raro la verdad, debe de aplicar algún tipo de modificación al crearlas que no permite obtener estos datos. PHP interpreta que no es una imagen, y lanza los avisos correspondientes. Otra cosa es usar la función `copy`, pero añades al servidor un archivo que no sabes que es ni que contiene, lo cual no es nada recomendable si es un script de uso público.

Comment: Por ahora lo dejare asi , me da pena por que es una web que he hecho y que me gustaria publicar y promocionar y tener este tipo de errores no me gusta nada... lo malo que aprendi php hace un mes y no entiendo por que ocurren estas cosas con las imagenes es un campo que aun no tengo del todo claro. Una vez mas gracias por tu ayuda y por el recibimiento cualquier duda que tengas intentare ayudarte!

Comment: Buenos días Oscar, llevo dándole vueltas al tema estos días, puede ser que se me escape algo en el formulario? alguna opción que haya que añadir para que se envíen completas el 100% de las imágenes?

Comment: Tengo buenas noticias Oscar ya he solucionado el problema, la imagen salia sin informacion por que no se ha podido subir correctamente por las configuraciones de Xampp y el tamaño que permitia. Tenia esta configuracion:
upload_max: 2M  
memory_limit: 2M
post_max_size: 2M

La nueva configuración es:
upload_max: 12000M  
memory_limit:12000M
post_max_size: 12000M

Tengo 16 de Ram pero por probar con 12000M tendria que valer dudo que alguien suba una imagen de mas de 11GB , lo bueno es que tras realizar el cambio funciona todo a la perfección. Curioso problema pero con una SOLUCION!

Comment: @Guillermo Enhorabuena!! Si que es un comportamiento extraño. No obstante, es bueno limitar el tamaño de los archivos que se suben. Lo normal, por ejemplo de una imagen de 4000x3000px suele estar en torno a los 12 Megas. Es un tamaño más que decente para cualquier móvil, cámara compacta o reflex para iniciados.